# How to Create Spray Paint Text Effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, text, photoshop-effects, effects

I've been trying to replicate a spray paint text effect in photoshop with hardly any luck. I downloaded multiple spray paint brushes/assets, the problem, however, is whenever you resize the brush to make it small enough to fit the text, the spray paint noise detail get lost and it looks like a regular soft brush.

I tried other methods as well like using distort/add noise/filter gallery but it doesn't look like the result I want.

Here's the ref image:

[image]

Here's my result.... :'(

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The main difference I can see is the letters are too sharp. Try blurring them a little.

Comment: I tried doing that, then adding a noise filter to dissolve, but it gets too blurry/not much of spray paint look. I even tried to hide the actual text layer and repaint the text shape with a spray paint brush but again.. it looked like a reg soft brush stroke.

Comment: Google 'spray paint photoshop' the info should already be out there. Youtube videos.

Comment: The info is surprisingly not there. All the ones I found were beginner level stencil tutorials

Comment: If you say so, i would try a combination of blur and noise in several layers. It will probably work at some point but i'll let others investigate this in detail.

Comment: That looks a lot like they just applied `Filter > Blur > Radial blur...` with `zoom` and `draft` quality + added grain on top. — As far as spray painted look goes, this isn't the greatest. A stencil font would help sell the spray painted look.

Comment: @Joonas this actually worked pretty good. The closest result I've gotten so far. I did that + manually adding spray paint brush around the type and it looks great. Thank you so much for the tip!

Comment: You can answer your own question if you want. Outline the major steps (I imagine 2-4 steps) and include some sort of end result image. If you do, I believe you have to wait around 8 hours before you can accept your own answer. I feel I don't deserve to answer and harvest the points given that I just threw that out there as a lazy guess. You figured it out, so you might as well get the points.

Answer (score 1):

Select the text layer and go to Filter > Blur > Radial Blur

Choose Zoom as the blur method and Draft for quality. Play with the value to fit your desired outcome.

Select the layer and go to Filter > Noise > add noise to give it a grainy look.

Optional: You can use spray paint brush to add further details around the edges.

Final Result: 
[image]

Details:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could play around with a Dissolve layer mode and a combination of noise and blurs to get something pretty similar. Here's the result I got:

[image: Spraypaint effect sample]

To do this, I grabbed the outline of the text, expanded its path by a few pixels, applied a feather to the edges, and chunked away some of the transparency.

Applying a Dissolve layer mode to that will give you a decent "base" for the spraypaint effect:

[image: Feather and opacity changes] [image: Dissolved effect]

I applied a Radial Zoom blue and a Gaussian Blur to that to add in some aliasing and flavor:

[image: Radial Zoom and Gaussian Blur applied]

Putting the solid text layer back on top and adding some monochromatic noise to everything will finish it up.